# Firebase Crashlytics does not show report for app crash on Device

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

I am installing firebase crashlytics in my app. It shows report of the crash on the dashboard when the app crashes on the simulator.But when I create ipa of the same code and run the app on the original device and the app crashes it does not create any report on the dashboard.What am I doing wrong while integration?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue by setting NO to Bitcode in buildSettings. And during the creation of ipa uncheck the box while asking for comileForBitcode.